# How to avoid wrapping when using XmlSerializerFormat for WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

I'm using WCF to create a SOAP web service, with predefined XSD contract, and C# types auto-generated from that XSD.

```
 [ServiceContract]
 [XmlSerializerFormat]
 public interface IEBooking10
 {
       [OperationContract]
       [XmlSerializerFormat]
       OTA_CancelRS OTA_Cancel(OTA_CancelRQ rq);
 }
```

OTA_CancelRQ & OTA_CancelRS are auto-generated types, with corresponding XML serialization attributes.
The parameters get wrapped in OTA_Cancel and OTA_CancelResponse elements, like this:

```
<OTA_Cancel>
   <OTA_CancelRQ> ... </OTA_CancelRQ>
</OTA_Cancel>
```

and

```
<OTA_CancelResponse>
   <OTA_CancelRS> ... </OTA_CancelRS>
</OTA_CancelResponse>
```

How can I avoid wrapping that WCF does to input parameters of the OTA_Cancel operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not handled by serialization but by message definition. At the moment you are using defaults which says that serialized data must be wrapped but the operation element. If you want to overwrite this behavior you must use [message contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx). Try something like this:

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
public class OTA_CancelRQMessage
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public void OTA_CancelRQ { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
public class OTA_CancelRSMessage
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public void OTA_CancelRS { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IEBooking10
{
   [OperationContract]
   [XmlSerializerFormat]
   OTA_CancelRSMessage OTA_Cancel(OTA_CancelRQMessage rq);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Message Contracts can be used with the XML Serializer format? I would expect to have to use the Data Contract format, but I've never tried combining the two.

Comment: @Programming Hero: Yes I believe they can. Data contract controls serialization of data but message contract controls the message itself. Data inside the message are still serialized by selected serialization method.

Comment: It worked :) Minor correction, properties cannot be void, change "public void OTA_CancelRQ { get; set; }" to public "OTA_CancelRQ OTA_CancelRQ { get; set; }" and for the response too.